# Getting error when relocating endpoint's place in Express.js

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, rest

I try to learn REST API and session based Authenticaion in express.js. But I got really interesting error when try to relocate the endpoints.

After relocating the endpoints I send a request to `/me` endpoint but I get an error. For instance;

```
// This code works fine
router.get("/me", sessionChecker, async (req, res, next) => {
  const { userId } = req.session.payload;

  const user = await UserService.findUserById(userId);

  return res.json(user);
});

router.get("/:userId", sessionChecker, async (req, res, next) => {
  const { userId } = req.params;

  const user = await UserService.findUserById(userId);
  return res.json(user);
});
```

to this;

```
// This code gives error
router.get("/:userId", sessionChecker, async (req, res, next) => {
  const { userId } = req.params;

  const user = await UserService.findUserById(userId);
  return res.json(user);
});

router.get("/me", sessionChecker, async (req, res, next) => {
  const { userId } = req.session.payload;

  const user = await UserService.findUserById(userId);

  return res.json(user);
});
```

I'am getting this error;

```
/Users/Desktop/projects/Curioso/backend/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:4913
  const castError = new CastError();
                    ^

CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "me" (type string) at path "_id" for model "User"
    at model.Query.exec (/Users/Desktop/projects/Curioso/backend/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:4913:21)
    at model.Query.Query.then (/Users/Desktop/projects/Curioso/backend/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:5012:15)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
  messageFormat: undefined,
  stringValue: '"me"',
  kind: 'ObjectId',
  value: 'me',
  path: '_id',
  reason: BSONTypeError: Argument passed in must be a string of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters or an integer
```

---

I couldn't understand what is the problem or logic of this error. Here is the rest of the code;

**index.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const session = require("express-session");
const MongoStore = require("connect-mongo");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const authRouter = require("./routes/auth");
const roomsRouter = require("./routes/rooms");
const usersRouter = require("./routes/users");
var cors = require("cors");
require("dot-env");

const app = express();

mongoose
.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URL)
.then(() => {
 console.log("Connected to DB");
})
.catch((error) => {
 console.log(error);
});

var whitelist = ["http://localhost:3000"];
var corsOptions = {
origin: whitelist,
methods: ["POST", "PUT", "GET", "OPTIONS", "HEAD"],
credentials: true,
};

app.use(cors(corsOptions));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use(
session({
 secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET_KEY,
 resave: false,
 saveUninitialized: true,
 cookie: {
   maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24,
   secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production",
   httpOnly: true,
 },
 store: MongoStore.create({
   mongoUrl: process.env.MONGODB_URL,
 }),
})
);
app.use("/auth", authRouter);
app.use("/rooms", roomsRouter);
app.use("/users", usersRouter);

app.listen(8000, () => {
console.log(`Example app listening on port 8000`);
});
```

---

**routes/user.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const { sessionChecker } = require("../middlewares/auth");
const router = express.Router();
const UserService = require("../services/user");

router.get("/", sessionChecker, async (req, res, next) => {
  const allUsers = await UserService.getAllUsers();

  return res.json(allUsers);
});

router.get("/:userId", sessionChecker, async (req, res, next) => {
  const { userId } = req.params;

  const user = await UserService.findUserById(userId);
  return res.json(user);
});
router.get("/me", sessionChecker, async (req, res, next) => {
  const { userId } = req.session.payload;

  const user = await UserService.findUserById(userId);

  return res.json(user);
});

module.exports = router;
```

---

**middlewares/auth.js**

```
const { HTTP_ERRORS } = require("../utils/constants");

const sessionChecker = (req, res, next) => {
  const userSession = req.session.payload.userId;

  if (!userSession) {
    return res
      .status(HTTP_ERRORS.UNAUTHORIZED.CODE)
      .send(HTTP_ERRORS.UNAUTHORIZED.MESSAGE);
  }

  next();
};

module.exports = { sessionChecker };
```

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are using pattern matching `/me` will go to the route `/:userId`. Express follows routes from first defined to last defined to find a matching route, this is why the order matters.
It is the practise to put the pattern matching as the last route so `/:userId` should be the last route.